# filter data between 2 dates in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, date, range, date-range, week-number

i was wondering if someone can help. i have tried some formulas but cant seem to work this out. i have a list of data with lots of dates some duplicate dates which are fine. i have data on a daily basis from 2015-2018. my aim is to try to put a number against each week between 2 dates so Monday-Sunday representing a week. so if the date falls between to dates bring back the week number. but of course there is a long list of date ranges and week ranges. does anyone know a formula or code to read to date and look between 2 separate dates and bring back a week number

thanks

Muj

Answer (score 0):

For a given date, weeknum() will return the week number:

[image]

Comment: is the formula from mon-sun

Comment: cell b3 just contains today() - this is an example, so you can build from it what you need. If the cell you target is the Monday date, as you imply you have both, then it will return that week.